# Login method in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-identity

i am trying to implement login method in asp.net. My problem is that my controller return that loging was successful, but I cant access any method marked as [authorize] - it returns http 401.
From the begining, my appsetings.json:

```
"JWTSettings": {
    "securityKey": "CoffeeShareSecretKey",
    "validIssuer": "CoffeShare",
    "validAudience": "https://localhost:44331",
    "expiryInMinutes": 5
  },
```

JWT in startup.cs:

```
var jwtSettings = Configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings");
            services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.GetSection("validIssuer").Value,
                    ValidAudience = jwtSettings.GetSection("validAudience").Value,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.GetSection("securityKey").Value))
                };
            });
            services.AddScoped<JwtHandler>();
```

JwtHandler.cs:

```
public class JwtHandler
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IConfigurationSection _jwtSettings;
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        public JwtHandler(IConfiguration configuration, UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _jwtSettings = _configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings");
        }
        public SigningCredentials GetSigningCredentials()
        {
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_jwtSettings.GetSection("securityKey").Value);
            var secret = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
            return new SigningCredentials(secret, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        }
        public async Task<List<Claim>> GetClaims(User user)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email)
            };
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
            }
            return claims;
        }
        public JwtSecurityToken GenerateTokenOptions(SigningCredentials signingCredentials, List<Claim> claims)
        {
            var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _jwtSettings.GetSection("validIssuer").Value,
                audience: _jwtSettings.GetSection("validAudience").Value,
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(_jwtSettings.GetSection("expiryInMinutes").Value)),
                signingCredentials: signingCredentials);
            return tokenOptions;
        }
    }
```

UsersController.cs:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("users")]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private readonly JwtHandler _jwtHandler;

        public UsersController(SignInManager<User> signInManager, UserManager<User> userManager, JwtHandler jwtHandler)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _jwtHandler = jwtHandler;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserDto userDto)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userDto.Email);
            var signingCredentials = _jwtHandler.GetSigningCredentials();
            var claims = await _jwtHandler.GetClaims(user);
            var tokenOptions = _jwtHandler.GenerateTokenOptions(signingCredentials, claims);
            var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);
            await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userDto.Email, userDto.Password, false, false);
            return Ok(new AuthResponseDto {IsAuthSuccessful = true, Token = token});
            }
```

Model and dto classes:

```
public class AuthResponseDto
    {
        public bool IsAuthSuccessful { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
    }
public class UserDto
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
public class User  : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public DateTime JoinedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

And this is response in swagger:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Swagger authorization
Add this to your `startup.cs`

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = @"JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n 
                      Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.
                      \r\n\r\nExample: 'Bearer 12345abcdef'",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer"
                });

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            },
                            Scheme = "oauth2",
                            Name = "Bearer",
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header,

                        },
                        new List<string>()
                    }
                });
            });
```

This will add an authorization button to your Swagger UI.

[image]

Click on it and then enter `Bearer` then space and the token that you get after login.

[image]

This will let you access all authorized methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a complete JWT verification demo before, you can refer to the following:

Demonstration effect：

[image]

First,open the appsettings.json file and change the section named Jwt:

```
"Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "testUser",
    "Audience": "user",
    "Key": "this is my custom Secret key for authnetication"
  }
```

Enable the JWT authentication scheme and swagger authorization configuration when the configuration starts, the entire code is as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using WebApplication129.Controllers.conf;

namespace WebApplication129
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
            services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
     .AddJwtBearer(options =>
     {
         options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
         {
             ValidateIssuer = true,
             ValidateAudience = true,
             ValidateLifetime = true,
             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
             ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
             ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
             IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
         };
     });
            services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.Add(new GroupingByNamespaceConvention());
            });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
            {   
                config.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description =
        "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer",
                    BearerFormat="JWT"
                });

                config.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
            },
            Scheme = "oauth2",
            Name = "Bearer",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,

        },
        new List<string>()
    }
});


                var titleBase = "Test API";
                var description = "This is a Web API for Test operations";
                var TermsOfService = new Uri("https://xxxxxx");
                var License = new OpenApiLicense()
                {
                    Name = "MIT"
                };
                var Contact = new OpenApiContact()
                {
                    Name = "Test",
                    Email = "Test@hotmail.com",
                    Url = new Uri("https://xxxxxx")
                };

                config.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = titleBase + " v1",
                    Description = description,
                    TermsOfService = TermsOfService,
                    License = License,
                    Contact = Contact
                });

               

                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                config.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });
        }

       
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(config =>
            {
                config.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test v1");
                
            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Log in and generate the jwt part as follows. Since I did not use it with a database, I customized a user:

Model:

```
public class Usuario
    {
        public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication129.Model;

namespace WebApplication129.Controllers.V1
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SegurancaController : Controller
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;
        public SegurancaController(IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            _config = Configuration;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] Usuario loginDetalhes)
        {
            bool resultado = ValidarUsuario(loginDetalhes);
            if (resultado)
            {
                var tokenString = GerarTokenJWT();
                return Ok(new { token = tokenString });
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
        }
        private string GerarTokenJWT()
        {
            var issuer = _config["Jwt:Issuer"];
            var audience = _config["Jwt:Audience"];
            var expiry = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120);
            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer: issuer, audience: audience,
expires: expiry, signingCredentials: credentials);
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var stringToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
            return stringToken;
        }
        private bool ValidarUsuario(Usuario loginDetalhes)
        {
            if (loginDetalhes.NomeUsuario == "TestName" && loginDetalhes.Senha == "TestPwd")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test and verify API:

```
[Route("list_data")]
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public Object  Data()
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.id = 1;
            user.userName = "Test";
            user.email = "test@xxx.com";
            user.address = "testAddress";

            return user;
        }
```